# JS newbie: NodeList returns null but has elements

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, nodelist

I had working Javascript/HTML/Jinja code when it was all in one file and now I want to split it into separate files.

My JS code was working before the split, but when I moved it to a new file, the commented out portion stopped working. I'm self-taught, so this might be something obvious but I haven't come across the right info yet. I can't access the element and I'm not sure why. How can I fix it? And: Is there some place that discusses why it worked in the same file but separating the code would break it like that? Thanks for any insight!

Before the move, my JS code was at the bottom of my HTML and I've seen that that sometimes makes a difference. I tried the `<script src>` at the bottom, but no difference.

My relevant HTML (rendered Jinja) code block:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <meta name="keywords" content="download,bookshelf">
  <meta name="description" content="UI with options to download Goodreads Bookshelf"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/download_page.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">;</script>
  <script src="/static/download_page.js"></script>
  <title> Download Page  | Group Bookshelf Tools</title>
</head>  
<body class="color-scheme-dark">
    <form action="/download_shelf/" method="post" name="choice_form">
      <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="...">
      <form-title>
        <label class="form-title" for="form_name">Download Form Options</label>
      </form-title>
      <form-row>
        <label class="item-label" for="shelf_choice">Shelf Choice</label>
        <select class="drop-down-menu" id="shelf_choice" name="shelf_choice" onchange="setShelfChoice()" required><option value="Generic Test Shelf">Generic Test Shelf</option><option value="Shelf One">Shelf One</option><option value="Shelf Two">Shelf Two</option></select>
      </form-row>
      <form-submit>
        <input class="btn form-submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">  
      </form-submit>
    </form> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried it without `this` but no change.

My JS code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setShelfChoice());

function setShelfChoice() { 
  let el = document.getElementsByName('shelf_choice');
  console.log("el type: ", typeof(el), el);
  console.log("el value: ", el[0].value);
  // let index = el.selectedIndex;
  // choiceValue = el.options[index].textContent;
  // console.log("setShelfChoice: ", choiceValue, "\n\n");
  // console.log("index: ", index);
}
```

When I reload the HTML page, it calls the function, and there is a Node 0 in the array and it has all the right values. But I'm not sure what I should be calling if not [0].

I tried changing `console.log("el: ", el[0].value);` to `console.log("el: ", el[0]);` the output just says undefined.

I tried adding an initialization but that hasn't affected anything:

```
function setShelfChoice() { 
  let el = document.getElementsByName('shelf_choice');
  if (el.selectedIndex == undefined) {
    el.selectedIndex = 0;
  }
  console.log("el: ", typeof(el), el);
  console.log("el: ", el.value);
```

[image: console output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setShelfChoice());
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When you put parentheses after a function name, you execute the function. In this case, you're not setting the shelf choice when the DOM content loads, you're executing it *immediately when that line is first read*.

You're passing the function's *result*, rather than the function itself.

Try without parentheses instead:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setShelfChoice);
```

Comment: Promising! Seems to work, but need to try a couple more things to verify.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. Just going to take some time to incorporate that. But it makes sense that the order of calls broke when I moved everything to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I think, here you are trying to get from Nodelist not from Node.

```
let index = el.selectedIndex;
console.log("el: ", el.value);
```

Maybe it should look like:

```
let index = el[0].selectedIndex;
console.log("el: ", el[0].value);
```

Do you start execute your js code after

```
window.onload 
document.onload
```

or

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Comment: `el[0].value` does not work, but `if (el.selectedIndex == undefined) {
    el.selectedIndex = 0; }; let index = el.selectedIndex;
  console.log("el value: ", el[index].value);` did. Actually, I think I'm having a scope issue. Changing `let el` to `var el` seems to have helped things along. I need to re-read the scope definitions.

Comment: Oh, and I'm doing a `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setShelfChoice());` in the JS file. I want the shelf to be set to a default and reset as needed. Will that be problematic?